# Correct preposition for 'limb'

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I encountered the following usage on a barrister's [blog](https://thesecretbarrister.com/2016/10/14/10-myths-busted-about-the-ched-evans-case/): '...not sure of both of the following limbs to the prosecution case,'.

I would've written 'the following limbs of the...'.

I searched Just The Word and checked for google hits of the exact phrase and it seems the first is uncommon.

Is this a correct usage?

Comment: I don't think this metaphoric use of "limb" is remotely idiomatic, so the choice of preposition is somewhat irrelevant. But if you insist on using it, probably ***of*** would work better.

Comment: Could you add some more context to your question as, for the moment, it is hard to get the exact meaning and wider implications?

Comment: This is a **blog** using *legal* terminology.  Don't try to parse it if you don't need to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But we do talk about *arms of government*, as well as possibly *an arm to government*  *A quango is an arm to government* (but perhaps not *an arm of government*). *Legs* are similarly employed. So I think it is a fair question, but my answer would be that either are possible, but *of* more common and conveying a slightly different meaning .

Comment: Good point.  It's also *British*, which is why it's "the jury were" rather than "the jury was".  Again, the terminology is not "normal English" (especially to a USAan), so don't waste your time analyzing it.

Comment: @WS2: Metaphoric government arms make more sense to me, because governments can easily be seen as "sentient" (and they're "similar to people", in that they have arms which enable them to do things). But for me, it's a stretch too far to "anthropomorphise" something as intangible as a prosecution case in that way (unless we bring in Keep these mind's point about *tests* that may be relevant to the case).

Comment: (But *cases* or *arguments* can certainly have metaphoric ***legs***, because things like that need ***support***. But *arms* don't usually "support".)

Comment: If one Googles for `"limbs to" case law` and ignores anything related to dismemberment (by horses), then there is quite a lot of legal stuff to find. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @FumbleFingers *One arm of a possible case against the South Yorkshire Constabulary, over the Hillsborough tragedy, is that they failed to ensure crowd safety, the other arm is that they tampered with the evidence*. I don't think I would raise an eyebrow if I read that in a broadsheet editorial.

Comment: Sigh!  If one substitutes "branches" for "limbs" in the original quote (ie, view the "limbs" as *tree limbs*), the gist of it is easy to get.  When you try to understand it as "arms" and "legs" you just confuse yourself.

Comment: @WS2: ***Arms*** can be metaphoric *approaches, lines of attack, etc.*, and ***legs*** can be metaphoric *supports, justifications*. But metaphoric ***limbs*** doesn't really work for me except maybe in the context of a multi-limbed octopus-like groper / sex pest.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I don't think anyone (except OP, obviously) is having a problem with the *meaning*. It's just a matter of whether this counts as the kind of usage a non-native speaker might usefully learn and be ready to actually *use* in future. I think not, but others obviously differ.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, as I said very early on, this is arcane terminology that is not worth trying to understand, unless you really need to, to pass a course or settle a lawsuit.

Comment: @Hot Licks: It's not meaningfully a "legal" usage - the source is just some blog or newspaper article, full of perfectly natural metaphoric usages like *She was blind drunk, X was grilled on her sexual history,* and *We’re back in the dark ages.* The writer just happens to have made one (imho, non-idiomatic) choice there. But personally I also think *the jury were not sure of **both** of the following limbs* should more properly be ***either***, so perhaps he just wasn't paying attention there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Actually, I'd have no trouble believing that "limb" is established legal jargon in England, in the sense of a legal analysis which "branches" like a tree.  But, if it is legal jargon that's all the more reason to ignore it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tend to agree that it is unusual to see *limbs* used metaphorically, in any context.

Answer (score 3):

The following suggests that the *limbs* may be ***of* a [(legal) test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_tests)** and ***applied to* a case** (or simply ***to* a case** for short). I suspect that the *limbs* constitute or are comparable to a singular check-list or [decision-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) (the test) that was developed for use in many different cases. So, they would be the test's limbs, not the case's limbs.

> In contrast, the Federal Court in other cases has identified *Perera* as having two cumulative limbs and **applied both limbs to the case** at hand. For example, Carr J in *Waiz v MIMA* identified the two limbs and stated that the correct approach was whether the applicant could be said to have been effectively prevented from giving his evidence in relation to a matter of significance for his claim or the Tribunal decision. Mansfield J in *Arif v MIMA* and Goldberg J in *Mahzar v MIMA* also dealt with **both limbs of the test** formulated in *Perera*.

http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/journals/UWSLawRw/2006/5.html

> **Legal tests** are various kinds of commonly applied methods of evaluation used to resolve matters of jurisprudence. In the context of a trial, a hearing, discovery, or other kinds of legal proceedings, the resolution of certain questions of fact or law may hinge on the application of one or more legal tests.
>
> Legal tests are often formulated from the logical analysis of a judicial decision or a court order where it appears that a finder of fact or the court made a particular decision after contemplating a well-defined set of circumstances. It is assumed that evaluating any given set of circumstances under a legal test will lead to an unambiguous and repeatable result.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_tests

Comment: Google finds no instances of *"**limbs** to the prosecution case"* (or *"**arms** to the prosecution case"*) on the Internet or Google Books, but *"**legs** to the prosecution case"* occurs once in each (in different contexts). We do actually talk about the ***legs*** in a decision tree, but I never heard of ***limbs*** being used like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although there aren't many hits, a few can be uncovered by Google. The decision tree is my own interpretation (as I'm more familiar with decision theory than with law stuff). It seems logical, but perhaps the use in law predates actual decision trees. I added _legal test_ to the answer.

Comment: I don't think it's really meaningful to refer to "the use in law" here, since to all intents and purposes there *is* no such use. Your example only peripherally involves a *[prosecution] case* insofar as the relevant *test* is part of that case. Bottom line: it's effectively a non-existent usage scenario, so the precise choice of preposition is really something of a moot point which can hardly be ruled on by finding the occasional written instance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant the use of decision trees, not the use of limbs. But anyway I did find some further hits from Australia and England/Wales and they use _limbs to (the case)_ a bit like one would use _pathways to (building a case)_. A bit of directionality there. The roads _to_ Rome as opposed to the roads _of_ Rome, which are not the same ones.

Comment: Yeah, I thought along those lines myself - it seems to me we'd normally understand *approaches **to** the case* as referring to ways in which the case can be *countered, argued against*, whereas ***elements*** or ***threads** to the case* would be taken to mean the actual lines of argument that *constitute* the case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you'd propose or argue in an answer that _limbs_ are more naturally interpreted here as _approaches_, then you'd have my upvote. Also feel free to edit this answer if you prefer that.

Comment: I have no answer to post or be upvoted, but I've no real reason to disagree with the substance of yours. As implied by my first comment, I could easily be persuaded that the question is OT POB simply because it's asking us to rule on which preposition is (idiomatically) preferred in a context that rarely if ever occurs (so there's no established preference anyway). But as yet I haven't voted at all on this page.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I haven't decided whether the question is OT. Perhaps you could limn the issues for me.

Comment: @deadrat: I must confess I had to *Search Google for 'limn'* there! I admit it may be a pretty weak case, but it seems to me if a usage doesn't occur [often enough], we can't really say how it *would* be used if it *did* occur. Because although there's often at least *some* logic to preposition choice, often there isn't - it's just whatever became established, so it now sounds "natural" simply because we're used to it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just Google `"limbs to" case law` and ignore everything related to body integrity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sorry, I didn't expect you take me seriously since your second comment was clear enough. I just couldn't resist the pun. I wouldn't blame you for being annoyed. I'm beginning to annoy myself.

Comment: @deadrat: I'd like to say I'm slow on the uptake but I get there eventually. Sadly, it's probably more accurate to say I'm slow on the uptake and clueless about which way to go when I *do* finally start moving. I don't usually get annoyed though - except now you've forced me to devote a few brain cells to remembering *limn*, I'll be really peeved if I make it to the Pearly Gates without ever being able to use it in earnest (in which case I might as well have wasted those brain cells smoking a joint instead! :)